# Convert SDF world made with building editor to URDF

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, ros-melodic, sdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ROS Melodic and Gazebo 9.6.0.

I will use Gazebo's Build Editor to build a building using a floor plant image, like this:

[image: image description]

You can see how it can be done in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7McYSJFAqlU).

I'm going to use that world with ROS, but its format will be SDF, and I need a URDF file.

Do I need to convert it to URDF or I can use it in SDF format?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323722/convert-sdf-world-made-with-building-editor-to-urdf/) by [Elric](https://answers.ros.org/users/30817/elric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2019-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS only works with urdf from what I've read and tried.

This python project should work for the conversion https://github.com/andreasBihlmaier/pysdf .

The usage looks like this `sdf2urdf.py model.sdf model.urdf` you can additionally add this before the model.sdf `-p plotfile.png` to export an image of model.sdf.

---

Originally posted by [c-mon](https://answers.ros.org/users/39492/c-mon/) with karma: 16 on 2019-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0